# wordpress mysql physical files .MYD not in /var/lib/mysql/dbname

Tags: server, mysql, wordpress

I installed wordpress on my home server (multisite install + varnish cache).

Now I'm looking into /var/lib/mysql/dbname to recover the mysql files, and here is what I find : All the important tables doesn't have the .MYD !!!

```
db.opt                           wp_easymail_stats.frm
wp_2_commentmeta.frm             wp_easymail_subscribers.frm
wp_2_comments.frm                wp_easymail_unsubscribed.frm
wp_2_easymail_recipients.frm     wp_gsom_subscribers.frm
wp_2_easymail_stats.frm          wp_links.frm
wp_2_easymail_subscribers.frm    wp_newsman_email_templates.frm
wp_2_easymail_unsubscribed.frm   wp_newsman_lists.frm
wp_2_links.frm                   wp_newsman_lst_default.frm
wp_2_ngg_album.frm               wp_ngg_album.frm
wp_2_ngg_gallery.frm             wp_nggcf_fields.frm
wp_2_ngg_pictures.frm            wp_nggcf_fields_link.frm
wp_2_options.frm                 wp_nggcf_field_values.frm
wp_2_postmeta.frm                wp_ngg_gallery.frm
wp_2_posts.frm                   wp_ngg_pictures.frm
wp_2_subscribe2.frm              wp_options.frm
wp_2_term_relationships.frm      wp_postmeta.frm
wp_2_terms.frm                   wp_posts.frm
wp_2_term_taxonomy.frm           wp_registration_log.frm
wp_2_wysija_campaign.frm         wp_signups.frm
wp_2_wysija_campaign_list.frm    wp_site.frm
wp_2_wysija_campaign_list.MYD    wp_sitemeta.frm
wp_2_wysija_campaign_list.MYI    wp_term_relationships.frm
wp_2_wysija_campaign.MYD         wp_terms.frm
wp_2_wysija_campaign.MYI         wp_term_taxonomy.frm
wp_2_wysija_email.frm            wp_usermeta.frm
wp_2_wysija_email.MYD            wp_users.frm
wp_2_wysija_email.MYI            wp_wysija_campaign.frm
wp_2_wysija_email_user_stat.frm  wp_wysija_campaign_list.frm
wp_2_wysija_email_user_stat.MYD  wp_wysija_campaign_list.MYD
wp_2_wysija_email_user_stat.MYI  wp_wysija_campaign_list.MYI
wp_2_wysija_email_user_url.frm   wp_wysija_campaign.MYD
wp_2_wysija_email_user_url.MYD   wp_wysija_campaign.MYI
wp_2_wysija_email_user_url.MYI   wp_wysija_email.frm
wp_2_wysija_form.frm             wp_wysija_email.MYD
wp_2_wysija_form.MYD             wp_wysija_email.MYI
wp_2_wysija_form.MYI             wp_wysija_email_user_stat.frm
wp_2_wysija_list.frm             wp_wysija_email_user_stat.MYD
wp_2_wysija_list.MYD             wp_wysija_email_user_stat.MYI
wp_2_wysija_list.MYI             wp_wysija_email_user_url.frm
wp_2_wysija_queue.frm            wp_wysija_email_user_url.MYD
wp_2_wysija_queue.MYD            wp_wysija_email_user_url.MYI
wp_2_wysija_queue.MYI            wp_wysija_form.frm
wp_2_wysija_url.frm              wp_wysija_form.MYD
wp_2_wysija_url_mail.frm         wp_wysija_form.MYI
wp_2_wysija_url_mail.MYD         wp_wysija_list.frm
wp_2_wysija_url_mail.MYI         wp_wysija_list.MYD
wp_2_wysija_url.MYI              wp_wysija_queue.frm
wp_2_wysija_user_field.frm       wp_wysija_queue.MYD
wp_2_wysija_user_field.MYD       wp_wysija_queue.MYI
wp_2_wysija_user_field.MYI       wp_wysija_url.frm
wp_2_wysija_user.frm             wp_wysija_url_mail.frm
wp_2_wysija_user_history.frm     wp_wysija_url_mail.MYD
wp_2_wysija_user_history.MYD     wp_wysija_url_mail.MYI
wp_2_wysija_user_history.MYI     wp_wysija_url.MYD
wp_2_wysija_user_list.frm        wp_wysija_url.MYI
wp_2_wysija_user_list.MYD        wp_wysija_user_field.frm
wp_2_wysija_user_list.MYI        wp_wysija_user_field.MYD
wp_2_wysija_user.MYD             wp_wysija_user_field.MYI
wp_2_wysija_user.MYI             wp_wysija_user.frm
wp_blogs.frm                     wp_wysija_user_history.frm
wp_blog_versions.frm             wp_wysija_user_history.MYD
wp_commentmeta.frm               wp_wysija_user_history.MYI
wp_comments.frm                  wp_wysija_user_list.frm
wp_domain_mapping.frm            wp_wysija_user_list.MYD
wp_domain_mapping_logins.frm     wp_wysija_user_list.MYI
wp_ean_newsletter.frm            wp_wysija_user.MYD
wp_easymail_recipients.frm       wp_wysija_user.MYI
```

Do you have an idea from where I could recover these .MYD files ? My articles are stored inside so quite a big amount of work.

And why precisely all the most important tables doesn't have their.MYD meanwhile the wordpress extension wysija not important at all has its all? I can't believe the bad luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.MYD is the data file for [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) tables. The tables that have only a .frm and no .MYD are probably [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-storage-engine.html). I recommend you dump the original database and restore it in the new machine, or copy the entire /var/lib/mysql directory.

- Dump: `mysqldump --user=<username> --password <database-name> > dumpfile.sql`
- Restore: `mysql --user=<username> --password <database-name> < dumpfile.sql`

Comment: thx! indeed I had to replace the whole mysql folder (and not just my base folder) which work perfectly. note : I had to use the password of the mysql I wanted to recover. what a relief!!